# Bad index file sha1 signature only in phpstorm

Tags: git, phpstorm

Commit works fine from the `git` command line and `git` gui (same repo)
but in `phpstorm` commit fails and returns:

```
bad index file sha1 signature
fatal: index file corrupt
```

I've tried

```
rm -f .git/index
git reset
```

But the issue persists.
What's going on here and how to fix the commit in `phpstorm`?

Comment: looks like a usual broken index issue. Strange that you can only repeat it when using pHPStorm. How many repositories do you have in your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a caching problem,  I just had something similar this morning, try :

```
git rm -r --cached . && git add .
```

**EDIT:** usually only the first line is enough to fix PhpStorm issues

```
git commit -am 'git cache cleared'
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

Verify inside your project if you have another .git folder, or git project.